# С помощью javascript отправить комментарий в instagram

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, instagram, javascript-events

Хочу написать и отправить комментарий с помощью javascript в instagram.
Но проблема в том, что не хочет отправляться.

Написал код таким образом:

```
//В форму добавляем комментарий
document.getElementsByClassName('Ypffh')[0].textContent = "Это комментарий!";
//Ждем пару секунд
setTimeout(function() {
//убираем disabled из формы отправки
document.querySelector("#react-root > section > main > section > div:nth-child(1) > div > article:nth-child(1) > div.eo2As > section.sH9wk._JgwE > div > form > button").disabled = true;
//нажимаем отправить
document.querySelector("#react-root > section > main > section > div:nth-child(1) > div > article:nth-child(1) > div.eo2As > section.sH9wk._JgwE > div > form > button").click();
}, 2000);
```

Но не реагирует instagram. Почему комментарий в instagram не отправляется с помощью javascript? (может чего-то не хватает)

Comment: в каком участке кода Вы отправляете что-либо в Instagram?

Comment: Там синяя кнопка есть (Опубликовать), если в консоли разработчика смотреть как в мобильной версии, в данном случае этот участок: document.querySelector("#react-root > section > main > section > div:nth-child(1) > div > article:nth-child(1) > div.eo2As > section.sH9wk._JgwE > div > form > button").click(); А в версии для персонального компьютера нет кнопки, поэтому возможно будет немного отличаться. Из-за отсутствии кнопки в версии для ПК для отправки используется клавиша Enter

Comment: Вот вам все [расписано](https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-private-api).

Comment: у автора вопроса вообще ничего не сказано про `Node.js`

Comment: не `textContent`, а `value`

Comment: да, value пробовал (innerText и innerHTML тоже). Та же ситуация. Пока что безрезультатно, не хочет отправлять комментарии

Comment: Почему disabled — true?

Comment: Заметь, что если вставить в `textarea` текст через js то при клике на него все стирается. Т.е. думаю, что их реакт при нашей вставке не учитывает, что мы вводили текст т.к. не срабатывал `oninput`, который вероятно висит на поле ввода, поэтому и кнопка не активируется. Вопрос в том, как  искусственно заставить реакт думать, что мы что-то написали

Comment: Вот погляди [https://i.imgur.com/5JCRAxv.png](https://i.imgur.com/5JCRAxv.png). Это из консоли реакта

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Долго ломал голову, но все же нашел решение. Работает в мобильной версии.

У каждого элемента, которым "владеет" реакт есть метод `__reactInternalInstance$XXXXXX`. В нем можно найти много интересного, в том числе и пропсы и хэндлеры элемента. К `onChange` мы и будем обращаться. Сначала нажимаем на кнопку комментария. Затем вычленим из `textarea` этот метод (`__reactInternalInstance$XXXXXX`), затем в его пропсах найдем `onChange` и передадим ему "искусственный" объект события `{target:{value:"Это коммент"}}`. Реакт подумает, что мы что-то пишем и все сделаем за нас. Кнопка активируется и мы на нее нажмем. Зайди на страницу с постом и выполни код. Если что-то непонятно - спрашивай.

```
window.FindReact = function(dom) {
  for (var key in dom) {
    if (key.startsWith("__reactInternalInstance$")) {
      return dom[key];
    }
  }
  return null;
};

document.querySelector("#react-root > section > main > div > div:nth-child(1) > article:nth-child(1) > div > section > span:nth-child(2) > button").click();
setTimeout(() => {
  FindReact(document.querySelector("#react-root > section > main > div > div:nth-child(1) > article:nth-child(1) > div > section > div > form > textarea")).memoizedProps.onChange({
    target: {
      value: "Это коммент"
    }
  });
  document.querySelector("#react-root > section > main > div > div:nth-child(1) > article:nth-child(1) > div > section > div > form > button").click();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Отлично. Про memoizedProps информацию не нашел. Можно узнать подробнее, что конкретно он делает?

Comment: @Ilnyr сорри, что оставил без ответа. Про memoizedProps информации мало, но, в общем, в нем хранится все, что пришло компоненту от родителя. Речь идет о React.js. В нашем случае хэндлер события ввода текста тоже пришел от родителя, а значит поле ввода текста управляемое. Мы "притворились", что написали в него что-то избавившись от "посредника" (необходимости писать текст вручную), передав нужный текст через искусственный объект события. Нужно знать React, чтобы лучше понимать весь этот механизм..